Indicate label for Horizontal line
I'm trying to find a way to add a label to show what red horizontal line indicates (in this case it's target) Can anyone help me to add a label for horizontal line which cross through y = 100, please?
const fetchDataAndRenderChart = (team_band, canvasId, colorIndex) => {
    fetch(`data.php?team=${team_band}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            const labels = data.map(item => item.digitiser);
                            const values = data.map(item => item.avg_qc_day);
        
                            const ctx = document.getElementById(canvasId).getContext('2d');
                            new Chart(ctx, {
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                    labels: labels,
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Average Units Per Day',
                                        data: values,
                                        backgroundColor: chartColors[colorIndex].backgroundColor,
                                        borderColor: chartColors[colorIndex].borderColor,
                                        borderWidth: 1
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                    plugins: {
                                        datalabels: {
                                            anchor: 'end',
                                            align: 'top',
                                            formatter: (value) => value,
                                            font: {
                                                weight: 'bold'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        annotation: {
                                            annotations: [{
                                                type: 'line',
                                                mode: 'horizontal',
                                                scaleID: 'y',
                                                value: 100,
                                                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.7)',
                                                borderWidth: 3,
                                                label: {
                                                    enabled: true,
                                                    content: 'Target: 100',
                                                    position: 'bottom'
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    scales: {
                                        y: {
                                            beginAtZero: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
                };

